# Fortran runtime error: No space left on device while running a GAMESS calculation

Tags: 16.04

I am getting an error msg for no space left on the devce. I am running a calculatioon on GAMESS software and it unexpectedly ends with the message "Fortran runtime error: No space left on device"
Please see image attached.[snapshot of the end of the calculation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQcQ0.png)

[snapshot of df command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CsrBJ.png)

Comment: Please edit your question to show us the complete output of the `df` command.

Comment: @user535733 done

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! [Please don't post images of text](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8713/85695). Instead, paste the text directly into your question and use the [formatting tools](//askubuntu.com/help/formatting) to format it as code.

Comment: That said, what directory is your process writing to? The `df` output shows that none of your drives are full, so the fortran process is probably deleting its temp files before exiting.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that your application fills up your `/`, and notices it's out of space, deletes the files and exits.

The output you provide shows that it writes to `/tmp`, which is on the root file system, where you have approx. 6 GiB free.

You should look into how much space the software you're running needs, and if the location of temporary data can be changed, say to `/home/username/tmp`, where you have over 400 GiB free.

Comment: Changing the location for **/tmp** worked. Thank you @vidarlo

Answer (score -1):

You have too many snaps installed on your device. Your problem is how to remove those old versions.

You already have a thread to resolve that in Super User: [How to remove old version of installed snaps](https://superuser.com/questions/1310825/how-to-remove-old-version-of-installed-snaps)

Comment: 8 snaps is in ***no way*** too many snaps, nor related to the issues described by the poster. There's no indication in the screenshots that more than one version is installed!

Comment: @vidarlo so what would be your input on this problem ? The /snap directory is totally full so something is going on here.

Comment: Snaps are essentially read only images. They will always be full. My take is simply that the process fills up /tmp, for some reason.